# Why can't an owner create a view?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

There is a user as HRS. I am creating a view in HRS as

```
CREATE VIEW HRS.RNS.....
```

I am getting

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

**Edit**

As i remember, i only execute following commands for the user and then my user can create tables

```
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO THE_USER;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO THE_USER;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO THE_USER;
```

How does my user automatically get rights to create table but not view?

Comment: Beginning in **Oracle Database 10g Release 2**, the `CONNECT` role has only the `CREATE SESSION` privilege (In previous versions it also contained the `CREATE VIEW` privilege.). For this reason, your code line `GRANT CREATE SESSION TO THE_USER;` is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create tables because the RESOURCE role has the CREATE TABLE privilege granted. To create a view, you need to have granted the CREATE VIEW privilege additionally, because, by default that privilege is not granted, not even to RESOURCE.

```
SQL> select privilege from dba_sys_privs where grantee='RESOURCE';

PRIVILEGE
----------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE TYPE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE OPERATOR
CREATE INDEXTYPE
CREATE TABLE
```

So you need to do the below:

```
grant create view to hrs;
```

Comment: Hmm, but i was able to drop a view. Is `Drop` assigned by default? How can i check?

Comment: A user does not need extra privileges for deleting owned objects, so one can drop already existing views, tables, etc. even when not able to create new ones.

Answer (score 1):

By "default" you can only select data from tables and views in your schema. To create different objects you need appropriate privileges granted.

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE to hrs;
GRANT CREATE VIEW to hrs;
```

and [so on](http://psoug.org/reference/system_privs.html).

Comment: I have modified the question, please see

Comment: Maybe select stmt in your view is using tables from schemes which are not available for this particular user.

Comment: There is another schema involved and rights to select from this schema to the user are already given. Furthermore, select query to create view is executing fine but the error is given when actual view is being created